# useMap() always says { current: undefined }

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-map-gl

I am using `react-map-gl` for a project. The map itself renders but i can't use `useMap()`. It always logs `{ current: undefined }`. Has anyone a solution?

My `layout.tsx` contains:

```
import { MapProvider } from "react-map-gl";
....
<div className="flex h-screen">
  <MapProvider>
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>

    <InternalMap />
  </MapProvider>
</div>
```

);

`InternalMap.tsx` looks like:

```
  import MapGL, { ScaleControl } from "react-map-gl";

  <MapGL
      ....
   >
    ....some more stuff
```

The children page looks like:

```
import { useMap } from "react-map-gl";

const { default: map } = useMap();
console.log(map, useMap())
```

Comment: I've never used that library but the documentation is different from your code in the useMap definition: const {current: map} = useMap();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up some imports in my monorepo and tried to imported `react-map-gl` from a wrong place with a version missmatch

Answer (score -1):

you have to use `An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL.`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactMapboxGl, { GeoJSONLayer } from "react-mapbox-gl";
import * as turf from "@turf/turf";
import geojsonStyles from "./geojsonStyles";
import "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.css";

import "./styles.css";

const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
  accessToken:"enter your access token"
});

class App extends Component {
  onDrawCreate = ({ features }) => {
    console.log(features);
  };

  onDrawUpdate = ({ features }) => {
    console.log({ features });
  };

  render() {
    const centerPoint = [-73.975547, 40.691785];

    var radius = 0.1;

    var options = {
      steps: 50,
      units: "miles",
      properties: {
        text: "test"
      }
    };

    const firstCircle = turf.circle(centerPoint, radius, options);

    const secondCircle = turf.circle(centerPoint, radius * 2, options);

    const thirdCircle = turf.circle(centerPoint, radius * 4, options);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Map
          style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9" // eslint-disable-line
          containerStyle={{
            height: "100vh",
            width: "100vw"
          }}
          zoom={[14]}
          center={[-73.975547, 40.691785]}
        >
          <GeoJSONLayer {...geojsonStyles} data={firstCircle} />
          <GeoJSONLayer {...geojsonStyles} data={secondCircle} />
          <GeoJSONLayer {...geojsonStyles} data={thirdCircle} />
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox URL: `https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-mapbox-gl-turf-mueyi?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A1%2C1-65%2C1`